# Google Sheets ignoring url links

Tags: google-sheets, import

I'm trying to upload a product to Google Marketplace. It says I can do it with Google Sheets. Two fields require a URL. When I import my tab-delivered text file into the sheet, everything goes in just fine, except the URL fields. It's like it completely ignores them. I don't get an error message at all. Any ideas?

Comment: one thing I tried to fix this that did work was.. instead of just importing the URLs in the fields, I tried importing `=IMPORTDATA("https://www.example.com") `  that didn't work either

Comment: I also just tried importing `=HYPERLINK("https://www.example.com", "link")`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some sample data in markdown or a link to a CSV  file.

Answer (score 0):

Your tab-delimited file might have formatting problems.

If you generated this file using code found in the wild, look for another code or use another code to fix it.

A workaround might be converting the tab-delimited file to a comma-separated one using a good conversion tool. Use Google or another search engine to find one. Tip: You might ask for as software recommendation in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com.

Another workaround is to use a text editor with find-and-replace features that support regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks.  I gave up on google-sheets and just went straight to a tab delimed file and that worked.  I ran into a new problem though and posted it here.  maybe you can help... https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/175287