# Google merchant center NEXT. Can't create Feed Lables. Can't even find instructions!

Tags: feeds, google-my-business, google-adwords, google-merchant-center, google-ads

I'm on Google's newer Merchant Center called "Merchant Center Next"  I managed to upload all my products successfully with feeds.   Now I want to promote a specific feed using Google Ads.  To do so, I have to choose a feed by entering a "Feed Label."  This new system has no instructions on how to create labels for my feeds.  There are instructions for Merchant Center Classic, but they are different and won't work here.   I've looked everywhere!  How can I create a feed label???